# How can I get Texture2D from material?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Firstly sorry for my English. I'm trying to get Texture2D from a material but I'm getting an error "Texture '' no data". If I tried with normal texture, there were no problem but only when I tried to get Texture2D, that returns the error.
Does anybody know how to get texture2D from a material??

Thanks

`//This is the line of code that I'm using now.`


`Texture2D temp = target.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture as Texture2D;`

Comment: Please provide the full exception. Texture is a base class for not only Texture2D, but also RenderTexture, Cubemap, etc. Are you sure it's a Texture2D?

Comment: check it if  materials.Lenght and textures.Lenght >0?